# USB flash drive/stick for MacBook Time Machine backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, usb, ssd

I'm looking for a USB flash drive/stick for my MacBook Time Machine backup.

It looks like people commonly use SSD, HDD or NAS, and I'm wondering if I can just get a small 512GB drive.

**Does a USB flash drive have any specific difference from SSD or HDD, like it has lower stability or anything? Could I just use it without any problem?**

(I have a tiny portable dock which can be connected with 3 USBs, 1 HDMI, 1 Etherneet cable and 1 C-type charger. I'm planning to keep the new USB plugged into it when I connected it with MacBook and an external monitor.)

Comment: If by "USB" you mean some kind of portable 'stick/thumb drive/flash memory' then no. They are extremely unreliable & slow.

Comment: It is usually recommended to get a drive that is 3 times the size of the drive (or data) that you are backing up. (As it will contain every revision, deleted file, new file, etc over months and even years.)

Comment: Yes I meant portable stick usb. I will get a big HDD with 3 times big capacity. Thank you for you guy's answers!